# How to display date format like "Today, 25 Mar 2014 15:18" in iOS?

Tags: iphone, date, ios7

I want to display date like `Today, 25 Mar 2014 15:18`, if the date is today's date.
Also expecting `Tomorrow, 26 Mar 2014 15:18`, if it is tomorrow's date and `Wednesday, 27 Mar 2014 15:18`, if it is day after tomorrow's date.

Anyone please help me.

Comment: Have you checked NSDateFormatter and setDoesRelativeDateFormatting: ? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:

Comment: @Volker: I have already reviewed this, but this couldn't reached to my expectation.

Comment: @SunilTarge Maybe you should post how you tried to use this date formatter and someone will be able to help you do it properly.

Comment: @SunilTarge, maybe _reviewing_ the docs was not enough, that would be the reason of why you have accidentally skipped this part: `doesRelativeDateFormatting` and `setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample from [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/setDoesRelativeDateFormatting%3a)

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSLocale *frLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:frLocale];

[dateFormatter setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:YES];

NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*60*24*1];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"dateString: %@", dateString);

NSDateFormatter *detailFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[detailFormatter setLocale:frLocale];

[detailFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm"];

NSString *detailString = [detailFormatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"detailString: %@", detailString);

NSString *finalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",dateString, detailString];

NSLog(finalString);
```

Comment: You are right, but I am expecting even date and time also with "après-après-demain" this. e.g. "après-après-demain, 27 Mars 2014 15:18"

Comment: I think you should combine it simple date formatter

Comment: ok you mean I have to combine two date format to display like that ryt?

Comment: I mean you should concatenate strings. I have already update the answer. Please check!

Comment: @Sunil Targe please do not forget to upvote/accept if the answer was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesn't directly support using relative date combined with absolute date.  What you'd have to do is to create two formatters, one with relative enabled and one without. Then compare the output strings (e.g. "Today" and "Mar 25") and if they are not equal, combine them: "Today, Mar 25", but if they are equal, just use one.

And as an aside, actually on "après-après-demain", I think you may have found a bug (either in docs or code). Do you actually set "après-après-demain"? I tried Apple's sample code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSLocale *frLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fr_FR"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:frLocale];

[dateFormatter setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:YES];

NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*60*24*3];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"dateString: %@", dateString);
```

Which Apple says produces output of `dateString: après-après-demain` no matter what your language is set to (as it switches the date formatter to French).

But when I ran the code on both iOS and OS X, I get the actual date: `Mar 28` (and if I change to `*2`, I get `après-demain`.

So, if you're seeing the same, I'd suggest filing a bug report with Apple.