# Create Timestamps on uitableview every 24 hours iOS like WhatsUp or Viber

Tags: ios, uitableview, timestamp

Hi there i am creating a message app similar to viber and whatsup 
i wanted to know if i can create timestamps for tableview or tableviewcell something like this
today, yesterday then example  2 May 2014, 1 May 2014 , 25 Apr 2014.
i created and im done with each cell timestamps that show the hour but i dont know how can i possibly create a group timestamp header which apears every 24 hours

so basicly it updates as header or something  every 24 hours 
any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631859/how-to-display-date-format-like-today-25-mar-2014-1518-in-ios/22631977#22631977 could be useful I think.

Comment: yeah thankyou ,but i mean how to i display it within the tablecells or tableview cuzi i have the code it works okeii but how do i display once in 24h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a well documented class to get relative date string from a date,

https://github.com/kevinlawler/NSDate-TimeAgo

It's easy to implement and add into project, also supports multiple languages.

Read everything there, it's what you want.